# How could I transform neural network estabished via model() to sequential()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, autoencoder

I was using TensorFlow 2.0 to build a fully connected neural network, a Denoising Autoencoder. The network structure is 128-64-32-64-128 (number of neurons) with 1000 data input and 1000 data output after five layers of network processing.

My codes are as follows (Model()):

```
# Denoising Autoencoder
input_size = 1000
hidden_size = 128   
hidden_size_2 = 64 
code_size = 32
output_size = 1000

x = Input(shape=(input_size, ))
hidden_1 = Dense(hidden_size,activation='relu')(x)           # 128
hidden_2 = Dense(hidden_size_2, activation='relu')(hidden_1) # 64
hidden_3 = Dense(code_size, activation='relu')(hidden_2)     # 32
hidden_4 = Dense(hidden_size_2,activation='relu')(hidden_3)  # 64
hidden_5 = Dense(hidden_size, activation='relu')(hidden_4)   # 128
r = Dense(output_size,activation='sigmoid')(hidden_5)

autoencoder = Model(inputs=x, outputs=r)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',metrics=["mse"])
```

and corresponding model.summary() are as follows:

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 1000)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               128128    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 32)                2080      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 64)                2112      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 128)               8320      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 1000)              129000    
=================================================================
Total params: 277,896
Trainable params: 277,896
Non-trainable params: 0
```

And I want to rewrite this neural network using sequential() mode (because a library of Python I need must use Sequential()). My codes are as follows:

```
input_size_1000 = 1000
hidden_size_128 = 128
hidden_size_64 = 64
code_size_32 = 32
output_size_1000 = 1000

# using sequential()
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential() 
# model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(input_size_1000,))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_size_128,input_dim=1000,activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_size_64,activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(code_size_32,activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_size_64,activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_size_128,activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size_1000,activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=["mse"])
```

and corresponding model.summary() are as follows:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               128128    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 32)                2080      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 64)                2112      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 128)               8320      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 1000)              129000    
=================================================================
Total params: 277,896
Trainable params: 277,896
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

I wondered why there was no input Layer in the rewritten code (I added input_dim=1000). At first I added `model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(input_size_1000,))`
, but it didn't work.  Then I command this line, and added inpu_dim=1000, there is still no input_layer. By the way, is there any problem with my rewrite? Because the library I'm going to be using doesn't have the input layer while it provides a flatten layer, is there any impact if the input layer is removed? What if I use a flatten layer instead of an input layer ( my data is a 1-dimension list) (because the sample in the library is dense after the flatten of the MNIST picture)? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the input layer is commented out, is that the case in your code?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain that clearly. The line I commented didn't have any effect on the model.summary() of my code, so I tried adding input_dim again, but it still didn't work.

Comment: I have also added this footnote to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Input dimension of Dense layer must be specified. In you sequential model  it is `input_dim`. With `print(model.inputs)` you will see the input tensor.

If using Flatten layer, `input_shape` of the Flatten layer must be specified, so that input dimension of next layer(Dense) is clear, for example: `tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[24, 24])`